# Jackson 2.2.2 ObjectMapper date format doesn't work for Joda DateTime

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my project I have following ObjectMapper class:

```
public class ObjectMapperImpl extends ObjectMapper {
    public ObjectMapperImpl() {
        super();
        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        registerModule(new JodaModule());
        setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

so as you can see I am using JodaModule to serialize/deserialize org.joda.time.DateTime

But my date format doesn't applies during serialization process and it produces date like this: `2013-06-15T09:50:08.541Z`

I took a look on JodaModule and I see that it registers following

```
addSerializer(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer());

public final class DateTimeSerializer
    extends JodaSerializerBase<DateTime>
{
    public DateTimeSerializer() { super(DateTime.class); }

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonGenerationException
    {
        if (provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)) {
            jgen.writeNumber(value.getMillis());
        } else {
            jgen.writeString(value.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider provider, java.lang.reflect.Type typeHint)
    {
        return createSchemaNode(provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                ? "number" : "string", true);
    }
}
```

so according to this code I can say that it never uses date format defined in configuration it simply uses `toString()` method to convert it to string

```
@ToString
    public String toString() {
        return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(this);
    }
```

and date format is hard coded and it's ISO.

So as I guess it's impossible to setup my own dateformat in ObjectMapper configuration for joda's DateTime.

Does it means that only solutions is to get rid of JodaModule and create my custom serializer/deserializer to support date format?

Looking for your oppinions.
Thank you.

Comment: Java's `DateFormat` and Joda Time's `DateTimeFormatter` are not the same, so it is pretty normal; doesn't the joda time plugin provide a way to specify a `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: I know it, but it is easy to convert joda DateTime to regular Date and then apply standard java date formatter. Anyway it still looks like there no api to configure it.

Comment: I suppose a patch will be welcome ;)

Comment: from my point of view, you should be able to configure JodaModule itself and then simply register it as usual, yeh, maybe it's a good thing to work on